# Is there a function similar to read_html() that can be used on data table or data frame types in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm attempting to webscrape from footballdb.com to get data related to NFL player injuries for a model I am creating from links such as this: https://www.footballdb.com/transactions/injuries.html?yr=2016&wk=1&type=reg which will then be output in a data table. Along with data related to individual player injury information (i.e. their name, injury, and status throughout the week leading up to the game), I also want to include the season and week of the injury in question for each player. I started by using nested for loops to generate the url for each webpage in question, along with the season and week corresponding to each webpage, which were stored in a data table with columns: link, season, and week.

I then tried to to use the functions map_df(), read_html(), and html_nodes() to extract the information I wanted from each webpage, but I run into errors as read_html() does not work for for objects of the data table or data frame class. I then tried to use different types of indexing and the $ operator with no luck either. Is there anyway I can modify the code I have produced thus far to extract the information I want from a data table? Below is what I have written thus far:

```
library(purrr) 
library(rvest)
library(data.table)

#Remove file if file already exists
if (file.exists("./project/volume/data/interim/injuryreports.csv")) {
  file.remove("./project/volume/data/interim/injuryreports.csv")}

#Declare variables and empty data tables
path1<-("https://www.footballdb.com/transactions/injuries.html?yr=")
seasons<-c("2016", "2017", "2020")
weeks<-1:17
result<-data.table()
temp<-NULL

#Use nested for loops to get the url, season, and week for each webpage of interest, store in result data table
for(s in 1:length(seasons)){
  for(w in 1:length(weeks)){
    temp$link<- paste0(path1, seasons[s],"&wk=", as.character(w), "&type=reg")
    temp$season<-as.numeric(seasons[s])
    temp$week<-weeks[w]
    result<-rbind(result,temp)
  }
}

#Get rid of any potential empty values from result
result<-compact(result) 

###Errors Below####
DT <- map_df(result, function(x){ 
  page <- read_html(x[[1]])
  data.table(
    Season = x[[2]],
    Week = x[[3]],
    Player = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(1) b') %>% html_text(),
    Injury = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(2)') %>% html_text(),
    Wed = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(3)') %>% html_text(),
    Thu = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(4)') %>% html_text(),
    Fri = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(5)') %>% html_text(),
    GameStatus = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(6)') %>% html_text()
  )
}
)
#####End of Errors###

#Write out injury data table
fwrite(DT,"./project/volume/data/interim/injuryreports.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your input data frame `result` is a datatable. When passing this to `map_df` it will loop over the columns(!!) of the datable not the rows.

One approach to make your code work is to `split` `result` by `link` and loop over the resulting list.

Note: For the reprex I only loop over the first two elements of the list. Additionally I have put your function outside of the map statement which made debugging easier.

```r
library(purrr) 
library(rvest)
library(data.table)

#Declare variables and empty data tables
path1<-("https://www.footballdb.com/transactions/injuries.html?yr=")
seasons<-c("2016", "2017", "2020")
weeks<-1:17
result<-data.table()
temp<-NULL

#Use nested for loops to get the url, season, and week for each webpage of interest, store in result data table
for(s in 1:length(seasons)){
  for(w in 1:length(weeks)){
    temp$link<- paste0(path1, seasons[s],"&wk=", as.character(w), "&type=reg")
    temp$season<-as.numeric(seasons[s])
    temp$week<-weeks[w]
    result<-rbind(result,temp)
  }
}

#Get rid of any potential empty values from result
result<-compact(result) 

result <- split(result, result$link)

get_table <- function(x) { 
  page <- read_html(x[[1]])
  data.table(
    Season = x[[2]],
    Week = x[[3]],
    Player = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(1) b') %>% html_text(),
    Injury = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(2)') %>% html_text(),
    Wed = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(3)') %>% html_text(),
    Thu = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(4)') %>% html_text(),
    Fri = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(5)') %>% html_text(),
    GameStatus = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(6)') %>% html_text()
  )
}
  
DT <- map_df(result[1:2], get_table)
DT
#>      Season Week          Player     Injury     Wed     Thu     Fri
#>   1:   2016    1   Justin Bethel       Foot Limited Limited Limited
#>   2:   2016    1     Lamar Louis       Knee     DNP Limited Limited
#>   3:   2016    1   Kareem Martin       Knee     DNP     DNP     DNP
#>   4:   2016    1     Alex Okafor     Biceps    Full    Full    Full
#>   5:   2016    1  Frostee Rucker       Neck Limited Limited    Full
#>  ---                                                               
#> 437:   2016   10   Will Blackmon      Thumb Limited Limited Limited
#> 438:   2016   10   Duke Ihenacho Concussion    Full    Full    Full
#> 439:   2016   10  DeSean Jackson   Shoulder     DNP     DNP     DNP
#> 440:   2016   10    Morgan Moses      Ankle Limited Limited Limited
#> 441:   2016   10 Brandon Scherff   Shoulder    Full    Full    Full
#>                       GameStatus
#>   1:  (09/09) Questionable vs NE
#>   2:  (09/09) Questionable vs NE
#>   3:           (09/09) Out vs NE
#>   4:                          --
#>   5:                          --
#>  ---                            
#> 437: (11/11) Questionable vs Min
#> 438: (11/11) Questionable vs Min
#> 439:     (11/11) Doubtful vs Min
#> 440: (11/11) Questionable vs Min
#> 441:                          --
```